# Comparing two lists and add a new column with the results

Tags: python, pandas

Comparing two lists and add a new column with findKB different

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['10', '20', '30', '40'],['50', '60', '70', '80']], 
               'B': [['a', 'b'],['c','d']]})
findKBs = ['10','90']


                  A       B
0  [10, 20, 30, 40]  [a, b]
1  [50, 60, 70, 80]  [c, d]
```

This will be the desired behavior

```
                  A       B         C
0  [10, 20, 30, 40]  [a, b]      [90]
1  [50, 60, 70, 80]  [c, d]   [10,90]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: thank you all, all your solutions works fine, but I have made a mistake in my ask, this is : the list findKBs change depending the data of the column B. Dont worry I will ask it again in another item. BTW thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
df['C'] = [find_kb[~np.isin(find_kb, a)] 
           for a, find_kb in zip(df['A'], np.array([findKBs] * len(df)))]
print(df) 
                  A       B         C
0  [10, 20, 30, 40]  [a, b]      [90]
1  [50, 60, 70, 80]  [c, d]  [10, 90]
```

Or we can use `filter`

```
df['C'] = [list(filter(lambda val: val not in a, find_kb))
           for a, find_kb in zip(df['A'],[findKBs] * len(df))]

#df['C'] = df['A'].map(lambda list_a: list(filter(lambda val: val not in list_a, 
#                                                 findKBs)
#                                         )
#                     )
```

`filter` is more difficult to read but more efficient:

```
%%timeit
df['C'] = [list(filter(lambda val: val not in a, find_kb))
           for a, find_kb in zip(df['A'],[findKBs] * len(df))]

194 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)



%%timeit
df['C'] = [find[~np.isin(find, a)] for a, find in zip(df['A'], np.array([findKBs] * len(df)))]
334 µs ± 38.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df['C'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: np.setdiff1d(findKBs,x))
534 µs ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: just `[[b for b in findKBs if not b in a] for a in df1['A']]` or `[*map(list,[set(findKBs).difference(set(a)) for a in df['A']])]` should scale well to i think (may be I am wrong) but since the series has lists I am guessing it would for a larger dataframe

Answer (score 4):

You can try this using [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) here.

```
df['C'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: np.setdiff1d(findKBs,x))

                  A       B         C
0  [10, 20, 30, 40]  [a, b]      [90]
1  [50, 60, 70, 80]  [c, d]  [10, 90]
```

To avoid lambda you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) here.

```
from functools import partial
diff = partial(np.setdiff1d, findKBs)

df['C'] = df['A'].map(diff)
```

Answer (score 2):

sub from `set`

```
df['C']=(set(findKBs)-df.A.map(set)).map(list)
df
Out[253]: 
                  A       B         C
0  [10, 20, 30, 40]  [a, b]      [90]
1  [50, 60, 70, 80]  [c, d]  [10, 90]
```